# How to delete selected records from TDBAdvGrid?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I want to delete multiple selected records which I have displayed at TDBAdvGrid. A number of records are being selected by checking checkbox in front of them. After clicking on Delete button it triggers procedure as follows. It is returning values of selected rows id successfully only problem with deletion of all records. It deletes only first selected record.

```
procedure TForm5.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
     i,j,idn: Integer;
     State: Boolean;
begin
  j := 0;
  for i := 1 to DBAdvGrid1.RowCount - 1 do
  begin
    if DBAdvGrid1.GetCheckBoxState(1,i,state) then
    begin
      if state then
      begin
        idn := StrToInt(DBAdvGrid1.Cells[6,i]);
        UniQuery1.SQL.Text := 'Delete from userplays where id = :id';
        UniQuery1.ParamByName('id').AsInteger := idn;
        UniQuery1.ExecSQL;


      end;
    end;
  end;

end;
```

It is deleting only first record in lineup. After deleting first record it breaks for loop and control goes back to TDBAdvGrid with updated data after delete.

[image]

Comment: Delete directly on the bound Dataset DBAdvGrid1.Datasource.Dataset.

Comment: Have you tried `DBAdvGrid1.SelectedRows.Delete`?

Comment: @kobik `DBAdvGrid1.SelectedRow` is there and it is property not function/procedure.

Comment: Use the `for` loop to gather all selected IDs into a comma-separated string, then pass that string to SQL similar to this: `DELETE FROM userplays WHERE ID IN (:IDList)` (I'm not exactly sure if you can pass that string as parameter, so you might need to simply concatenate it with the rest of the SQL Expression; also, don't forget to remove the last comma in that string). If you don't have too many items selected, this method is more efficient since it deletes all records at once.

Comment: @bummi, @kobik, @lightbulb  After prolonged efforts finally sorted out problem. As per ur suggestion I did it with bound dataset. Did some silly mistakes in between due to which it took long time but learned many important things related to `DBAdvGrid Dataset`, how to move `dataset` to appropriate location etc..

Comment: The most important part is to set `DBAdvGrid dataset` to the very first record before you begin for loop operation for deletion of selected records because in this case when you selects many records via `checkbox`, `dataset` is always pointed to the last record you selected so it is important to move it to first record/row.

Comment: Another problem is that it is deleting record immediately, due to which after deletion of first record it is deleting a record next to second selected record so on...

Comment: When I set PageMode property of TDBAdvGrid to the False record deletion working perfectly. Why there is always problem when Pagemode is set to the true , as it is automatically popping one record up at run time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final code based on suggestion is as follows

```
  j := 0;
  DBAdvGrid1.BeginUpdate;
  for i := 1 to DBAdvGrid1.RowCount - 1 do
  begin
    showmessage('inside rowcount loop');
    if DBAdvGrid1.GetCheckBoxState(1,i,state) then
    begin
      if state then
      begin
         DBAdvGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.First;
         DBAdvGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.MoveBy(i - 1 - j);
         DBAdvGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.Delete;
         j := j+1;
         continue;
      end;
    end;
  end;
```

This code works perfectly only when `PageMode := False`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestion above, I would like to make another suggestion...

```
  //DBAdvGrid1.BeginUpdate;
  query.First;
  for i := 1 to DBAdvGrid1.RowCount - 1 do
  begin
    if DBAdvGrid1.GetCheckBoxState(1,i,state) then
    begin
      if state then
      begin
         //you can do whatever you want with the current selected record
      end;
    end;
    query.Next;
  end;
```

I think this is easier then using the MoveBy...
I even never changed PageMode, it's still on true. No idea if it's coincidence or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cyBookmarks  in the OnCheck event , with Virtual Table.
It creates a list of all records selected, and you can list them with 
cyBookmarks.bookmarklits.count, so my example is like this :

```
procedure TForm2.cyDBGrid1CheckBoxClick(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
    if cyBookmarks1.AddCurrentRecord then 
        begin 
            cyBookmarks1.BookmarkList.InsertBookmark(cyDBGrid1.CheckedList.CurrentRecord); 
            cyDBGrid1.Invalidate ; 
        end 
    else 
        begin 
            cyBookmarks1.RemoveCurrentRecord; 
            cyDBGrid1.Invalidate; 
        end; 
    if cyBookmarks1.BookmarkList.Count>0 then 
        begin 
            VirtualTable1.GotoBookmark(cyBookmarks1.BookmarkList.Items[0]); 
            lbl1.Caption:=VirtualTable1.FieldByName('N_ENREGISTREMENT').AsString; 
        end; 
end;
```

Comment: procedure TForm2.cyDBGrid1CheckBoxClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
if cyBookmarks1.AddCurrentRecord  then
  begin
   cyBookmarks1.BookmarkList.InsertBookmark(cyDBGrid1.CheckedList.CurrentRecord);
   cyDBGrid1.Invalidate ;
  end
  else
  begin
  cyBookmarks1.RemoveCurrentRecord;
  cyDBGrid1.Invalidate;
  end;
  if cyBookmarks1.BookmarkList.Count>0 then
     begin
      VirtualTable1.GotoBookmark(cyBookmarks1.BookmarkList.Items[0]);
      lbl1.Caption:=VirtualTable1.FieldByName('N_ENREGISTREMENT').AsString;

     end;
end;